# How to have different text in each pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm very new to coding and am trying to create a portfolio website.

I have used a pop-up code sourced from W3 Schools.
The idea is that when you click on each small illustration, a full-screen pop-up appears with text. I have been able to do it successfully for one pop-up when you click on the flower.

My problem is, I am now unsure how to do a pop-up for each small illustration with different text.

I have added my code to this post, as well as screenshots of it in the browser to give you a better idea of what it looks like with the illustrations. [Website Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igvkS.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated! I'm very stuck.

```js
/* Open */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.height = "100%";
  }
  
  /* Close */
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.height = "0%";
  }
```

```css
/* Universal Styles */

body, html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", san-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: #9486f2;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;  
}



/* Navigation */

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
  }


a:hover {
    color:#adff2f;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}


nav {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    float: right;
}


nav div {
    padding: 5px 0;    
}


/* Logo */

header img {
    height: 80px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;    
}




/* Heart & Icons */

.container .rowtop {
    text-align: center;   
    
}


#flower {
    position: relative;
    right: 120px;  
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100px;
}


#adobe {
    position: relative;
    left: 190px;  
}


.container .rowmiddle {
    text-align: center;   
    
}


#code {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 370px;
    right: 30px;  
}


#heart {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 60px;
    
}


#pudding {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 330px;
    left: 50px;  
}


.container .rowbottom {
    text-align: center;   
    
}


#certificate {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 210px;
    right: 120px;
}


#tv {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 190px;
}




/* Pop-Ups */


/* The Overlay (background) */
.overlay {
    /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */   
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0.95;
    background-color: #cc90ec; /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
  }
  
  /* Position the content inside the overlay */
  .overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%; /* 25% from the top */
    width: 40%; /* 100% width */
    text-align: left; /* Centered text/links */
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 46px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
 
  
  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color:#adff2f;
  }

 


  
  /* Position the close button (top right corner) */
  .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  
 


/* Wavy Text */

.wavy
{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below -12px linear-gradient(
        transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
}


.wavy span
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #adff2f;
    font-weight: 400;
    animation: animate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}


@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    10%
    {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    30%,100%
    {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}








/* Footer */

h5 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", san-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 14px;
}


footer {

    padding-left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dom Pooley</title>
        <script src="main.js" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/dominiquepooley/Documents/03_Dom Personal/05_Portfolio/Portfolio 2020/Portfolio2020/resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,700;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    

<!-- Header -->
    <body>
        <header class="flex-container">
            <img src="/Users/dominiquepooley/Documents/03_Dom Personal/05_Portfolio/Portfolio 2020/Portfolio2020/resources/images/DomPooley_Logo_01.png"">
        <nav>
            <div><a href= "./about.html">About</a></div>
            <div><a href= "./work.html">Work</a></div>
            <div><a href= "./contact.html">Contact</a></div>
        </nav>
        </header>






<!-- Heart and Icons -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="rowtop">
          <img id="flower" src="resources/images/Pansy_01.png" onmouseover="this.src='resources/images/Pansy_02.png' " onmouseout="this.src='resources/images/Pansy_01.png'" onClick="openNav()">
          <img src="resources/images/Adobe_01.gif" id="adobe" alt="" height="120">
        </div>
        <div class="rowmiddle">
          <img src="resources/images/Code_01.gif" onmouseover="this.src='resources/images/Code_02.png' " onmouseout="this.src='resources/images/Code_01.gif'" id="code" alt="" height="40">
          <img id="heart" height="500" src="resources/images/Dom_Heart_01.png" onmouseover="this.src='resources/images/Dom_Heart_02.png' " onmouseout="this.src='resources/images/Dom_Heart_01.png'"/>
          <img src="resources/images/Pudding_01.gif" id="pudding" alt="" height="120">
        </div>
        <div class="rowbottom">
          <img src="resources/images/Certificate_01.gif" id="certificate" alt="" height="100">
          <img src="resources/images/TV_01.gif" id="tv" alt="" height="110">
        </div>
      </div>





<!-- Pop-Ups -->

<!-- The Overlay -->
<div id="popup" class="overlay">

  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div id="flowerpop" class="overlay-content">
    <p>Thanks to COVID-19, I now have a new hobby -I have been growing, picking, pressing and coating flowers in resin to make jewellery. I would include a photo but they still have that "primary school project vibe"... 
      <br><div class="wavy">
        <span style="--i:1;">*</span>
        <span style="--i:2;">W</span>
        <span style="--i:3;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:4;">t</span>
        <span style="--i:5;">c</span>
        <span style="--i:6;">h</span>
        <span style="--i:7;"> </span>
        <span style="--i:8;">t</span>
        <span style="--i:9;">h</span>
        <span style="--i:10;">i</span>
        <span style="--i:11;">s</span>
        <span style="--i:12;"> </span>
        <span style="--i:13;">s</span>
        <span style="--i:14;">p</span>
        <span style="--i:15;">a</span>
        <span style="--i:16;">c</span>
        <span style="--i:17;">e</span>
        <span style="--i:18;">*</span>
    </div></br></p>
  </div>
</div>






 <!-- Footer Section -->   
 <footer>
  <h5>Copyright Dominique Pooley 2020</h5>
</footer>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to implement your own pop-ups (and not following W3Schools), or maybe pick one of the existing pop-up libraries, there are literally thousands of available libraries for this.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a small change in css.

```
a:hover {
    color:#adff2f;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

You have to remove `letter-spacing: 5px;` from css file.

then code looks like :

```
a:hover {
    color:#adff2f;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: The question was: "_How to have different text in each pop-up_". How does this answer to the question?

Comment: you have to make each text put in spam and click event perform then you can open popup.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you've mentioned, it sounds like you're trying to have a generic pop-up/modal as a HTML element and then when you click on different illustrations it will open the modal and the modal would contain some text related to that illustration that you clicked on.

What you want to do, is keep your modal, which appears to be the `#popup` element, add an `onclick` to each illustration that runs a function which dynamically injects some text by targetting the heading where you need the text to be, for example:

```js
toggleModal (title, subtitle) {
  const headingEl = document.querySelector('[data-your-heading]')
  const subtitleEl = document.querySelector('[data-your-subtitle]')

  headingEl.innerText = title
  subtitleEl.innerText = subtitle

  // run some code to hide/show the modal below here
}
```

Next, attach the `data-your-*` attributes to whichever tag you want to update text with, for instance a `<p>` tag within your generic HTML modal/pop-up.

And then on each of your illustrations, you add an `onclick` function and pass the arguments of what text you want, for example:

```js
<button type="button" onclick="toggleModal('My Title', 'My Subtitle')">Show Illustration 1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give this a go!